# Automatic deploy from CVS to WebServer

Tags: cvs

A small introduction:
We are developing HTML prototypes (html, css, images, js files) using CVS as our repository. We need to show to the customers almost every change and discuss with them those changes. Those costumers are in another building or in another country, therefore we need to send in some way the prototypes. In order to avoid zillions of mails with zips and more zips, we develop a script that does a "checkout" every 10 mins from the working branch and we "share" the updated folder using a webserver. With this solution, we share only a link that contains the last working copy of our prototype via HTTP.

We cannot use SVN/Git or other "less painful" revision control system.

Questions:

- is there any way to improve this process?
- can we monitor the CVS in another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the loginfo hook of CVS to perform actions after each checkin. But beware that the script will be run for every file which is touched during a commit.

Comment: Thanks you, do you have any example? how could I monitor this files?

Comment: There is a loginfo sample in /CVSROOT of your repository.

Comment: I do not have access to those files from the computer that has the web server and actually does the checkout. Any other alternative?